# How to navigate with arrow keys between radio buttons when input type radio is hidden and label is shown?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a radio button group and the radio buttons are hidden while the associated label is shown.  Let's say
that the radio button group is called color.  When a certain color is chosen, I highlight the label with that color.  This works great when all I click the labels.  But I would also like to navigate between the labels using arrow keys.  I realize that since the input is hidden, the arrow movements are not taking effect.  But is there any way to get around this?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue"><label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="red"><label for="red">Red</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="green"><label for="green">Green</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="color_selected"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="color"]').change(function() {
        var prevColor = $('#color_selected').val();
        if (prevColor) {
            $('#' + prevColor).next('label').css({'background':'#FFFFFF'});
        }
        var color = jQuery(this).val();
        $(this).next('label').css({'background':color});
        $('#color_selected').val(color);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkqLj/

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `display:none`, mock the hiding by positioning the input field way off.

```
input {
    left: -1000px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nkqLj/1/)***